# Date/Time picker in html + django

Tags: html, django, web

I am trying to find solution for my problem, but unfortunately there is no answers. I need one button which will paste the current date/time in one of the inputs on my html form. The website is made with django.

I need to put button beside `{{form.data_godzina_one}}`.

```
        <div id='wazne'>
        {{form.Trailer.label}}:  {{form.Trailer}} <br><br>
    {{form.operacja.label}}:  {{form.operacja}} <br><br>
        {{form.wydzial_one.label}}: {{form.wydzial_one}} <br><br>
        {{form.data_godzina_one.label}}:  {{form.data_godzina_one}}<br><br>
    {{form.driver_one.label}}:  {{form.driver_one}}<br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your form? (and related model if using ModelForms). This seems like more of a JavaScript question if you want a button to set the input value. But a django form can set a default of `datetime.now`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've already tried 'datetime.now', but form will be edited at least one time, and automatically it will put edited date/time.

Form:

```
 <form action="" method="POST" style="margin-left:20px;" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id='wazne'>
        {{form.Trailer.label}}:  {{form.Trailer}} <br><br>
    {{form.operacja.label}}:  {{form.operacja}} <br><br>
        {{form.wydzial_one.label}}: {{form.wydzial_one}} <br><br>
        {{form.data_godzina_one.label}}:  {{form.data_godzina_one}}<br><br>
    {{form.driver_one.label}}:  {{form.driver_one}}<br>
    </div>
    <div  id='wazne'>
        <p style='font-size: 11px;'>Przestawienie nr 1</p>
        {{form.wydzial_two.label}}:  {{form.wydzial_two}}<br><br>
        {{form.data_godzina_two.label}}: {{form.data_godzina_two}}<br><br>
    {{form.driver_two.label}}:  {{form.driver_two}}<br>
    </div>
    <div id='wazne'>
        <p style='font-size: 11px;'>Przestawienie nr 2</p>
        {{form.wydzial_three.label}}:  {{form.wydzial_three}}<br><br>
        {{form.data_godzina_three.label}}: {{form.data_godzina_three}}<br><br>
    {{form.driver_three.label}}:  {{form.driver_three}}<br>
    </div>
    <div id='wazne'>
        <p style='font-size: 11px;'>Przestawienie nr 3</p>
        {{form.wydzial_four.label}}:  {{form.wydzial_four}}<br><br>
        {{form.data_godzina_four.label}}: {{form.data_godzina_four}}<br><br>
    {{form.driver_four.label}}:  {{form.driver_four}}<br>
    </div>
    <div id='wazne'>
        {{form.wydzial_zakonczenie.label}}:  {{form.wydzial_zakonczenie}}<br><br>
        {{form.data_godzina_zakonczenie.label}}: {{form.data_godzina_zakonczenie}}<br><br>
    {{form.driver_fifth.label}}:  {{form.driver_fifth}}<br>
    </div>
    <div id='wazne'>
    {{form.truckID.label}}:  {{form.truckID}}<br><br>
        {{form.zadanie.label}}: {{form.zadanie}}<br><br>
        <p style='font-size: 13px;'>Wybierz kraj, gdy zadanie to ''Zagranica''<p><br>
    {{form.kraj.label}}: {{form.kraj}}<br><br>
        {{form.add_informations.label}}: <br>{{form.add_informations}}<br><br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj">
```

ModelForm

```
class MainTable_Nutricia(models.Model):

Trailer = models.ForeignKey(Naczepy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='naczepa', related_name='Naczepa', null=True)
operacja = models.ForeignKey(Operacje_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Operacja', related_name='operacje', null=True)
wydzial_one = models.ForeignKey(Wydzialy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Wydział rozpoczęcie', blank=False)
data_godzina_one = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Czas rozpoczęcia", blank=False)
driver_one = models.ForeignKey(Kierowcy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Kierowca_jeden', verbose_name='Kierowca', null=True)
wydzial_two = models.ForeignKey(Wydzialy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wydział_dwa', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Wydział')
data_godzina_two = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Czas', blank=True, null=True)
driver_two = models.ForeignKey(Kierowcy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Kierowca_dwa', verbose_name='Kierowca', null=True, blank=True)
wydzial_three = models.ForeignKey(Wydzialy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wydział_trzy', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Wydział")
data_godzina_three = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Czas', blank=True, null=True)
driver_three = models.ForeignKey(Kierowcy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Kierowca_trzy', verbose_name='Kierowca', null=True, blank=True)
wydzial_four = models.ForeignKey(Wydzialy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="wydział_cztery", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Wydział")
data_godzina_four = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Czas", blank=True, null=True)
driver_four = models.ForeignKey(Kierowcy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Kierowca_cztery', verbose_name='Kierowca', null=True, blank=True)
wydzial_zakonczenie = models.ForeignKey(Wydzialy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="wydział_pięć", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Wydział zakończenie")
data_godzina_zakonczenie = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Czas zakończenia', blank=True, null=True)
driver_fifth = models.ForeignKey(Kierowcy_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Kierowca_piec', verbose_name='Kierowca', null=True, blank=True)
zadanie = models.ForeignKey(Zadania_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
truckID = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='ID')
kraj = models.ForeignKey(Kierunki_Nutricia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
add_informations = models.TextField(verbose_name="Dodatkowe informacje", null=True, blank=True)
checked = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Sprawdzone', default=False)
```